# Possible to convert private key to RSA after SSL cert installed?

Tags: ssl-certificate, rsa, plesk

Need to sort out some confusions here as I'm not very clear on this topic.

Current I had purchased a SSL cert from third party, submit to server support and then they have installed the necessary certs in the server. I can see from the Plesk panel that the .key, .crt and -ca.crt is installed.

But actually I have a requirement where the private key need to be in RSA.

So my question is, can I convert the existing .key to RSA and upload to overwrite the existing key? Or I need to tell my vendor to redo the process to generate the key as RSA and then reinstall SSL again?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to RSA"?  What are you converting *from*?  The private key was created as part of your CSR, and you can't change it afterward (except by creating a whole new CSR and getting a new certificate).  But you haven't said what's in your `.key` file, and it sounds like you might be thinking that the `.key` extension itself means it's not RSA, and that's not correct.

Comment: Previously I use OpenSSL to generate private key and convert to RSA afterwards, which is also private key but begin with `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY....` and then generate the CSR for submission to get the CRT. So do you mean that in my case the process of generating key, CSR, installing cert.... has to redo?

Comment: I think you're confusing the format of your key file with the type of key stored within it.  "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" is PKCS#1 format for an RSA key, but there are other container formats (like PKCS#8) that can also hold RSA keys.  You can't change the type of the key itself, but you can convert between different container formats with OpenSSL (or other tools).